# how ..? search string in textbox with 100k characters and compair with listbox box having 50k items...?

Tags: vb.net-2010

I have one textbox and one listbox ,

-Textbox contain at least 100 000 characters with no space like this,
(AJDJCBDJ384959372DHFJANSJD34FKFKGJGGLPSJ ) and so on .

-Listbox contain atleast 50k items (of string) like this ,

item1: GHDJDJDJD47582957FJFKGWPD

item2:
YOODJFJEEEBDJFJF45837892QQQHDJDJDJDJDJJDDJDJFJJFUIPO

M using this code :

```
For each dd1 as string in listbox1.items

dim rohit as string = textbox1.text

if rohit.contain (dd1) Then 
msgbox("Match Found") 
else 
msgbox("")

end if 
next
```

My Problem in this code is that it is very slow while comparison. It took 15 sec.

if the item falls in between 10k to 12k then it took 3 sec. that means if index number is smaller then it take less tym where else if index number is larger in listbox item list then it tooks long tym to search.

example:
if my item is in a 100 index then it took long but if it is in 50th index then it quit quick

Answer (score 0):

After going through source code of

```
String.contains(String str)
```

I found out that it actually uses index method which scans each  character of input sting to match each character of   string str Which is not so efficient .

Actually you can use trie data structure to Make search faster and its time complexity is O(size of String str )

Here is link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Comment: my code search quick if there is only one line in textbox but if more then 20 lines it took lot of tym ... i think the database is not a problem .....

Comment: I only theoretically studied trie So i cant make code in vb.net    .But i think if you make your code multithreaded than i think it will work faster You can make two threads one start from first item second from last item

Comment: i have tried as u said and yes it works and the time reduce from 15 sec to 8 sec but not more then that ... i wNt to reduce to  1 to 2 sec to search how to achieve that ....?